# How do i simplify a block of code that ParseInt Retrieves from localstorage variables

Tags: javascript, variables, math, nan, parseint

I have this game which i am designing where i store 1 or 0 values as correct or incorrect answers in the local storage in variables q1 - q6.

Since local storage doesnt store numbers as integers, before my main page loads i parseInt all of my variables to get the integers. Although some of them havent been declared as anything yet so they seem to be NaN or null, so when i try to compute the addition of all of the variables, it gives me NaN unless i use this mess of a code.

```
    if (isNaN(totalpoints)) totalpoints = 0;
    if (localStorage.getItem("points") === null){
    localStorage.setItem("points", "0");
    }
    var q0 = parseInt(localStorage.q0);
    var q1 = parseInt(localStorage.q1);
    var q2 = parseInt(localStorage.q2);
    var q3 = parseInt(localStorage.q3);
    var q4 = parseInt(localStorage.q4);
    var q5 = parseInt(localStorage.q5);
    var q6 = parseInt(localStorage.q6);
    if (isNaN(q0))q0=0;
    if (isNaN(q1))q1=0;
    if (isNaN(q2))q2=0;
    if (isNaN(q3))q3=0;
    if (isNaN(q4))q4=0;
    if (isNaN(q5))q5=0;
    if (isNaN(q6))q6=0;
    var totalpoints = totalpoints + q0 + q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6;
    localStorage.setItem("points", totalpoints);
```

I am trying to think of a way where i can simplify this code into maybe a few lines using a loop for the variables possibly or something?
Can anyone give me any sense of direction on how i can approach this or help me possibly?
Im just not sure as it seems like i got to parseInt the localstorage variables all individually?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having multiple separate numeric-indexed properties, consider using a single array instead:

```
const qArr = localStorage.qArr
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.qArr)
  : new Array(7).fill(0);
```

Then, instead of assigning to the `q` variables, assign to an index of the `qArr`, and to save it, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
qArr[3] = 555;
localStorage.qArr = JSON.stringify(qArr);
```

To add up all the items in the array, you can use `reduce`:

```
totalPoints = qArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, totalPoints);
```

Since it sounds like this is all in one self-contained script, I'd [highly recommend](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/issues/175) consolidating all the relevant items that need to be stored into a single object too, if at all possible, so as not to pollute localStorage with lots of separate properties that really deserve to be in a single place, rather than spread out, eg:

```
const dataObj = localStorage.pointsData
  ? JSON.parse(pointsData)
  : {
      totalPoints: 0,
      qArr: new Array(7).fill(0)
    };
```

Then, do stuff with `dataObj.totalPoints` and `dataObj.qArr`, and when you need to save it, do something like:

```
localStorage.pointsData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an object.

You can store object as `answers` in `localStorage` and update the values.

So suppose `answers` object is something like this

```
answers = {
   q0: 10,
   q2: 20
}
```

Then it won't matter whether key is present or not, as you can loop through object to get total sum

```
let total = 0;

for (const key in answers) {
    total += answers[key];
}
```

Of course you have to store that object in localStorage like this

```
localStorage.setItem('answers', JSON.stringify(answers));
```

And while getting you have to parse it

```
const answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('answers'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to replace multiple values with one single array.
So, your saving function could be something like this:

```
function savePoint(point) {
  var points = JSON.parse(localStorage.points || "[]");
  points.push(point);
  localStorage.points = JSON.stringify(points);
}
```

And you will calculate the total like this:

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var points = JSON.parse(localStorage.points || "[]");
  return points.reduce(function(total, point) {
    return total + point;
  }, 0);
}
```

Anyway, I suggest to think about a data model to store the points and using `JSON.stringify` + `JSON.parse` to store it in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have points `q0` - `q7` plus the `points`, there are 8 variables. Now, if we carefully go through your code, things that are common

1. You fetch a variable from a local storage
2. You convert it to integer
3. You check whether it is NaN. If NaN, you set to 0.
4. Finally, you use the variable to calculate the sum

   Okay. So we will try to write a function that does steps 1-3 with

```
function oneForAll(variableName){
  if (localStorage.getItem(variableName) === null){
    localStorage.setItem(variableName, "0");
  }
  var variable = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(variableName));
  if (isNaN(variable)) {
      variable = 0;
  }
  return variable
}
```

I basically used most of your lines so that you can relate to it.

Now, for step 4, we need to use our function to get the total sum. Also, we need a loop.

```
var listOfVariables = ["points", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7" ]

var totalPoints = 0;

// loop over the list of variables
listOfVariables.forEach(variableName => {
  totalPoints += oneForAll(variableName);
});

// finally you set the new calculated total points
localStorage.setItem("points", totalpoints);
```

Hope this is helpful.